# How do I get rid of "Network may be monitored" in KitKat?

Tags: security, certificates, 4.4-kitkat

Ever since I've installed my own CA in the key store I'm getting warnings that the network may be monitored. Well, I guess that's a valid warning if I don't trust these certificates, but I really trust my own CA here; even more than the ones preinstalled.

How do I get rid of this warning I see at least once per day popping up?

This is on stock Android 4.4 KitKat on a Nexus 5.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was looking into the same issue, and it was answered on XDA http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2537794

In short - it is possible if your phone is rooted to move the certificate to the System section.

Very annoying that it is not possible to exclude certificates from this warning - it only produces noise when I know that the cert is OK to use.

Comment: This is similar to the answer by Langley, but it actually works for 4.4. Please include essential parts from the link inside your question. It is preferable over simply linking on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, can you try putting the certificate into the "System certificates" as shown here:

http://nblock.org/2011/09/03/how-to-update-the-android-certificate-store/

I don't have a linux system on hand at the moment, so I cannot really try it out. Let me know if it works!

Comment: That blog post applies to pre-ICS (2.3) and in addition to that, it's considered Samsung-specific and for rooted devices only. I don't think it's a good idea to perform this to avoid a warning. And I can't perform that - I don't want to root my device just for this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that any solution besides waiting for Google to fix this will result in your system being rooted or even having a custom rom/fix which requires an unlocked bootloader.

Answer (score -4):

The easiest way is to install the certificate using Settings -> Security , and then go to a terminal window and do this:

```
$ su
# cp /mnt/ext_card/data/misc/keychain/certs-added/* /system/etc/security/cacerts/
```

Comment: As far as I can see this is the same answer as the currently accepted answer. http://android.stackexchange.com/a/57836/38289