# Strange notifications on "network"

Tags: networking, internet, certificates

[image]

I've been getting this notification, well, basically ever since I moved to my Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo, which is my current phone. Up till a few days ago, I simply hit `Clear` and ignored this, wondering what it might mean. But now I've started getting the following too:

[image]

Note that the only certificate I ever installed was [my Uni's wifi certificate](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89558/pin-being-requested-twice), which should definitely NOT cause this, as with my older phone I had similar certificates for almost 2 years, changing 3 or 4 of them, NEVER SEEING ANYTHING like this. So what *do* those notifications mean and what should I do about them (if anything)?

Comment: Related: [How do I get rid of “Network may be monitored” in KitKat?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56292/how-do-i-get-rid-of-network-may-be-monitored-in-kitkat)

Answer (score 2):

Guess you're using Kitkat (or newer) on that device? I'm afraid in that case you've got to live with that (you will always receive this warning as soon as you've installed a custom certificate – see [official changelog regarding this](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/enhancements/enhancements44.html)<sup>1</sup>) – or root your device and install certificates as "trusted certificates" only.

### How to install a certificate as "trusted system certificate"

As said, this requires a rooted device. Further, I'm not sure whether it works for certificates other than "CA root certificates" (those used to sign other certificates). For sure you'll need a `.pem` certificate for the following – and here are the steps:

```
# find the hash value of the certificate
openssl x509 -inform PEM -subject_hash_old -in cacert.pem | head -1
# prepare your certificate. The following line assumes the has is d12345:
openssl x509 -inform PEM -text -fingerprint -in cacert.pem > d12345.0
# now on the Android device: remount `/system` to be able to write to it
mount -o remount,rw /system
# move the certificate to the `cacerts` dir:
cp d12345.0 /system/etc/security/cacerts/
# now adjust the file permissions:
cd /system/etc/security/cacerts/
chown root:root d12345.0
chmod 0644 d12345.0
# finally, remount `/system` read-only
mount -o remount,ro /system
```

<sup>(source: [Android without Google 2: ownCloud](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-2))</sup>

---

<sup>**1:** thanks to [Andrew T.](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/44325/andrew-t) finding that link for proof in the comments</sup>

Comment: My certificate is `.p12`. Anyway, I do not have Kitkat -- or at least I can't find it among my `Apps` and Play store has the `install` button for `Kitkat 4.4`. What do you refer to as «newer»?

Comment: Lollipop (5.x)? What is your exact Android version (see *Settings › About phone* on your device if unsure)? *Kitkat* is the first version I've heard that trouble for (I'm not 100% sure whether it might have been introduced even earlier).

Comment: @Izzy `Model number GT-I9301I`, `Android version 4.4.2`, `Baseband vrsion I9301IXXUANI2`, `Kernel version 3.4.0-2688263 dpi@SWDD6216 #1`.

Comment: I won't ever notice, as I only use above described method. I don't like to be told which lock screen types I have to use, just because I've installed some certificate for a web site ;) Apart from that, I've not yet updated beyond 4.1, so I cannot check.

Comment: @MickG That's Kitkat (4.4.2), as I assumed.

Comment: @Izzy what _is_ `Kitkat`?

Comment: One of the many [Android versions](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/android-versions/info). They all have some "sweet nick-names". I'll update the tag-wiki (link) for you ;)

Comment: After researching a little bit, I think it's really been since KitKat (Android 4.4). I checked my testing device and it turned out to be 4.4.2 (not 4.2), so this is correct. (I also found dupe question that I posted on OP's question after that). Edit: and I found the [official changelog regarding this](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/enhancements/enhancements44.html)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewT.! Integrated that proof-link with my answer (giving credits to you of course ;)